# Retrieving details from Amazon using fog in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, fog

I am currently working in a project with Rails, and I have faced the need to import the existing server details from Amazon using the fog library.

I have tried some initial code to get the access to AWS, and at this point I have got the connection with the credentials.

The issue is that when I continue to get that instance details, it does not return anything.

```
require 'fog'
aws_credentials = {
:aws_access_key_id => "ACCESS ID"
:aws_secret_access_key "SECRET ID"
}
conn2 = Fog::Compute.new(aws_credentials.merge(:provider => 'AWS'))
conn2.servers.all.each do |i|
puts i.id
end
```

Could anyone please help me fixing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amazon provider in fog defaults to using the us-east-1 region. It could be that your servers are in another region. To specify a different region by passing the `:region` into your `Fog::Compute` constructor. Valid regions include ['ap-northeast-1', 'ap-southeast-1', 'ap-southeast-2', 'eu-west-1', 'sa-east-1', 'us-east-1', 'us-west-1', 'us-west-2'.

So for instance if you are using region ap-northeast-1, your code would look like the following:

```
require 'fog'
aws_credentials = {
:aws_access_key_id => "ACCESS ID"
:aws_secret_access_key "SECRET ID"
}
conn2 = Fog::Compute.new(aws_credentials.merge(:provider => 'AWS', :region => 'ap-northeast-1' ))
conn2.servers.all.each do |i|
puts i.id
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my region is eu-west-1b,but now its getting error like this when i add that region
getaddrinfo': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError) (Excon::Errors::SocketError)

Comment: Try using region 'eu-west-1'.

Comment: Thank you so much, i have got that, is there any way to get the regions to populate before to access the details

Comment: I am not sure if I follow your question. You need to specify the region when you create the service.

Comment: why should i give the region like this "ap-northeast-1" instead of "ap-northeast-1b"